# Animation when a usercontrol loads in window

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls

I am new to WPF and don't know anything about WPF animations. here i am doing a project where all the (different data entry,retrieval) forms are usercontrols and added to a Window when requested . I just want to add simple slide-in, slide-out or fade animation when these usercontrol loads into the window, like before closing one usercontrol and loading the second one.

Structure is something like this:

Window --> usercontrols --> (ordinary text boxes,listboxes etc etc)

where in window xaml, i placed a dockpanel in which i loads usercontrols when relative button is pressed. i may be using wrong things at wrong places, but thats how i learn new things.
 any sample code or tutorial for these animations will be a great help !! Thanks

Comment: tutorials for such a common topic as `WPF animations` are usually better covered by Google, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Expression Blend to apply animation your controls.

It provides a configurable GUI way of defining animations.

Look at the top-most answer to this question for details: [WPF - Animated User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360931/wpf-animated-user-control)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using blend then there are somethings that i forget the name of but basically, like in flash you have states and you in code select the state on certain events. In the transition for the states (which as i remember was top left in blend) you can choose how and from where the animation occurs as well as how long it takes.

Alternatively you can check up on it [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx)